# What languages / environment allow high precision numbers?

Tags: numbers, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm using Mathematica for a specific project, requiring-precision floating point numbers. Mathematica seem to support that - all values are symbolic, and when evaluated numerically, you can ask for the precision you want. For example, you can have a number with 1000 digits after the decimal point.

Are there any other environments which allow this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are quite a few libraries (JScience, GNU Multi Precision Library, C++ BigInt, ...),  applications (R, bc, MATLAB, ...) and programming languages (C#, Erlang, J, Python, ...) that support this. You can find a list of them in the Wikipedia article [List of arbitrary-precision arithmetic software](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software).

Answer (score 0):

Go primitives do not support arbitrary-precision for all numeric values, but it's worth mentioning that its numeric constants do.

From the [GoLang blog](https://blog.golang.org/constants):

> Numeric constants live in an arbitrary-precision numeric space; they are just regular numbers. But when they are assigned to a variable the value must be able to fit in the destination.

This let's you define and perform arithmetic with huge numerical values like

```
const Huge = 1e1000
```

There is also a standard library package [big](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) which implements arbitrary-precision arithmetic.